# If MySQL's InnoDB PRIMARY columns are automatically indexed, why is the index length reported as zero?

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key, innodb

This is my MySQL InnoDB database. Notice how the table `days` reports the `index length` as `0`.

[image]

This is the table data, scheme and indexes:

[image]

As you can see, the table has a `PRIMARY` column defined. This should be indexed, right? So there should be a certain index length.

However, when I actually add the `INDEX` column, such as this:

[image]

The table suddenly reports a certain `index length`, as can be seen here:

[image]

So I wonder: what is going on? What exactly is the index length and why does it not take PRIMARY keys into account, if they are indexed?

Comment: Your primary key is a compound key (multiple fields), so the length is reported on the **FIRST** field in the key, which is `user`. since `days` is essentially piggy backing, it has a 0-length key, because it's already been accounted for on the user field.

Comment: @MarcB: are you sure about this explanation? Because this happends on all the tables which have no INDEX defined and contain a PRIMARY key on a single field only. A simple table as `id` PRIMARY, `username` reports the index length as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB stores the table rows in a [clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html) based on the primary key. So, the `data_length` shows the size of pages occupied by the primary key.

`index_length` shows the size of pages occupied by secondary (non-primary) indexes.

---

Re your comment:

Yes, it's unnecessary in this table to create an extra index on the first column of your primary key. MySQL doesn't *prevent* you from creating such a superfluous index because it trusts you know what you're doing. :-)

You can use a tool like [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) to analyze your metadata for duplicate indexes. In one such case I found 400GB of wasted space due to duplicate indexes!

Comment: Does it mean that adding the INDEX key to the USER column just produces more useless data, since USER is already indexed in the PRIMARY key?